# Using jquery in chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to setup a slider bar in the chrome extension popup.  My slider bar code requires jquery but unfortunately, my program will not recognize the jquery code in my popup js.  Here is the error produced when I inspect the popup:

```
script.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
```

Here is my script.js code that creates the slider bar. Given that it does not execute past the first line, it seems that I have a jquery issue:

```
$('.application-progress').slider({
range: "min",
min: 0,
max: 100,
animate: true,
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#progress").html(ui.value + "%");
    }
});

$("#progress").html($(".application-progress").slider("value") + "%");

$("input, select").change(function() {
    var percentage = 0;
    $('input, select').each(function() {
        if ($.trim(this.value) != "") percentage += 10;
    });
    $(".application-progress").slider("value", percentage);

    $("#progress").html(percentage + "%");
});
```

Here is the html code for my popup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Slider Bar!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="progress"></div><div class="application-progress"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to include jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Coz, [jQuery UI Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) needs jQuery UI library to be loaded after jQuery.

Comment: Hmm, followed your guidance and I no longer receive the uncaught error.  However, my popup is coming up blank.  Upon inspection, it appears everything executes properly as no errors are shown...

Comment: That means he answered your question correctly. The rest of it is up to you! :)

Comment: @Lance Have you found the issue with the other one?

Comment: Sorry, but I am a long time viewer of stack overflow but this was my first ever question--how do I "accept?"  I clicked the arrow to turn it green and clicked the up arrow.  Is that it?  Sorry!

Comment: @Lance That's all! `:)`